# Visual Studio Warning Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core Version 2.2.2.0 matches Version 2.2.3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

When I compile my Asp.Net MVC project the following warning is displayed:

```
Warning CS1702
Assuming assembly reference 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy.
```

I have no packages and no assemblys matching the version 2.2.2.0 in my solution.

This error only is displayed when I compile my views (adding the following option in my .csproj)

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning your solution?
If you havn't, try that first by right clicking the solution and then click clean.

You can also try and delete your packages folder and then get a new one.

Sorry for making an answer but I can't make comments since my reputation is too low.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried cleaning my solution and deleting my packages folder, as you suggest, but it don't works, the warning remains displaying.